# MVC Only get flagged active data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a MVC project and I got the data displayed in a model, view and controller.

I have the following in my controller:

```
return View(db.Department.ToList());
```

I also have a column on my database called **DeptActive**. I only want to get the results which are active, how would I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `System.Linq` and [`Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-5.0) to get all active departments:

```
return View(db.Department.Where(d => d.DeptActive).ToList());
```

Or if you have a field representing whether you want active or inactive departments:

```
return View(db.Department.Where(d => d.DeptActive == isActive).ToList());
```

which will get *active* departments when `isActive == true` or *inactive* departments when `isActive == false`.